# XSLT: How to round a list of floats in a attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following input xml node:

```
<text bbox="143.430,683.264,147.982,695.231">foo</text>
```

What I want to have is:

```
<span class="ocrx_word" title="bbox 143 683 148 695">foo</span>
```

So far I can change commas to spaces and attribute name like so:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:variable name="bbox" select="translate(@bbox, ',', ' ')" />
  <span class='ocrx_word' title="bbox {$bbox}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

I see there are `round()` and `str:split()` (from EXSLT) functions, but I can't quite get how to mix them together to get what I want.

Comment: There isn't actually a `split()` function in xpath. Can you use XSLT 2.0 though? If you could, the function you would be able to use then is `tokenize()`. Thanks

Comment: Also, you mention about rounding, but `147.982` would round to `148`. Do you want to `floor()` instead of `round()`?

Comment: @TimC I'm working with [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt), which does not support XSLT 2.0, as far as I can see. But it does support EXSLT, where `split()` comes from. I'll update question.

Comment: It's actually no difference for me is it round or floor. Once I can do one, I should be able to do another as well.

Comment: @TimC I see, EXSLT also provides `str:tokenize()` function. So I may be able to use it. Can you please show how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to test this (as I don't have a XSLT processor to hand that supports EXSLT strings), but in theory, if `lxml` does, you want to do something like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:variable name="bbox" select="str:tokenize(@bbox, ',')" />
    <span class="ocrx_word">
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(@bbox, ',')">
          <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="round(number(.))" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that works indeed! The only thing's missing is a space between rounded numbers in the output. E.g. `<span class="ocrx_word" title="111683114695">foo</span>`

Comment: Ah yes. I've amended my answer to include the spaces.

Comment: Yes, I see. Now the problem is something is swallowing the whitespace. I.e. if it would be `<xsl:if test="position() > 1">_</xsl:if>`, I'd get `111_683_114_695`. But I guess, that's lxml.

Comment: Alright, I've found it! `<xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>` does the trick.

Comment: Ah yes. XSLT documents have whitespace nodes stripped out, with the exception of ones in `xsl:text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="text">
<xsl:variable name="bbox" select="for $i in tokenize(@bbox,',')
return floor(number($i))" />
<span class='ocrx_word' title="bbox {$bbox}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</span>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, lxml can't compile this xpath expression. `lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: XSLT-variable: Failed to compile the XPath expression 'for $i in str:tokenize(@bbox,',') return floor(number($i)'.
`

Comment: The `for ... in .. ` statement is only supported in XSLT 2.0 and above unfortunately.